# How to move an object up with an action?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Wasn't exactly sure how to title this, but I need to count up how many enemies a player killed before they die and respawn for my point and health system.

My idea is to  set up a variable that gets 1 added to it on each collide and then when the player is killed it takes the amount of that stored score variable and uses it for the point and for my health system, which is to move something up on the screen up.

Some super pseudo code would look like:

```
var storedPlayerScore = 0


    var HealthPlus = SKAction.moveBy(CGVectorMake(0, (10 * storedPlayerScore)), duration: 0.05)
```

I've got both of those defined in my Gamescene.

and then down in my didbegincontact I'd just do like storedplayerscore++ whenever the two correct objects collide.

So before when I was just making sure the health going up worked, I had a number in where the stored variable was, but when I use this it gives me "Gamescene.type doesn't have a variable named storedPlayerScore"

Am I on the right track here? How do I clear the error I'm getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access something on the type itself rather than on an instance of that type.

```
class GameScene {
    var storedPlayerScore: Int = 0
}

var score1 = GameScene.storedPlayerScore // Error

let myGameScene = GameScene()
var score2 = myGameScene.storedPlayerScore // Works
```

This confusion is probably brought on by the names you're choosing for your variables.  In your code above, you have a variable called `HealthPlus` which is named with a capital first letter.  That makes it look like a type instead of an instance.  The convention for variable names is start with a lowercase letter, while type declarations start with a capital letter. So it should be `healthPlus` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the super clear explanation.  Works perfectly. Have a good one!